# Can DAG be used with the REST API?

Tags: yodlee

It appears that DAG is only available as a hosted service.  How do I test my code integration programmatically through the REST API for the following methods?

addSiteAccount1
getMFAResponseForSite
putMFAResponseForSite

Is there a way to do this with real account data through the API?

Answer (score 0):

DAG is a simulator for real account and is available to upload an XML to test few real account scenario and then adding the DAG account using the APIs to see how data is fetched.

Every account on DAG has a siteID , username and password which can be used to link it as a real account.
So you can use the SiteID to get the login form of the DAG site and then use the username and password to link the account.

For testing
getMFAResponseForSite
putMFAResponseForSite

use the Dag Site SecurityQA or Dag Site TokenFMPA as sites to add.

for more info on dag please visit 
https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Indy_FinApp_Knowledgebase/Sample_Data/Dummy_Account_Generator

Comment: Unfortunately a call to addSiteAccount1 results in the following JSON response.  {"errorOccured":"true","exceptionType":"Exception Occured","refrenceCode":"_7c40ed7b-6a14-4736-a120-a113d5dfecb7"}